# Compiler error stack trace

Tags: compiler-errors, g++

When compiling on CentOS 5.9 [`gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)`]. My application is failing to compile with the following error:

```
/opt/qt64/4.7.3/include/QtCore/qendian.h: In function ‘T qbswap(T) [with T = long long unsigned int]’:
/opt/qt64/4.7.3/include/QtCore/qendian.h:278: error: ‘bswap_64’ was not declared in this scope
/opt/qt64/4.7.3/include/QtCore/qendian.h: In function ‘T qbswap(T) [with T = unsigned int]’:
/opt/qt64/4.7.3/include/QtCore/qendian.h:282: error: ‘bswap_32’ was not declared in this scope
/opt/qt64/4.7.3/include/QtCore/qendian.h: In function ‘T qbswap(T) [with T = short unsigned int]’:
/opt/qt64/4.7.3/include/QtCore/qendian.h:286: error: ‘bswap_16’ was not declared in this scope
```

I do not think there is anything wrong with Qt 4.7.3 as the code compiles correctly on MSVC2010 and Fedora 9 [`gcc version 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8) (GCC)`] both compile against Qt 4.7.3 without incident.

**My question, is there a way to get GCC to tell me any or all of the following: The last place in my code before reaching this error OR The full code trace that led to this compiler error OR Some other method for me to figure out how to fix my code?**

Comment: CentOS probably doesn't have these `bswap` functions, or they're in a different header.  Did you check?

Comment: No I did not. How would I check that?

Comment: `grep -R bswap /usr/include/*`

Comment: It appears to be defined in multiple places `/usr/include/asm-i386/byteorder.h
/usr/include/asm-x86_64/byteorder.h
/usr/include/bits/byteswap.h
/usr/include/byteswap.h
/usr/include/mtd/jffs2-user.h
/usr/include/netinet/in.h`

Comment: OK, cool.  So is `qendian.h` looking for them somewhere else?

Comment: I can't see where it is including them if it is. Source: `https://github.com/RLovelett/qt/blob/4.7/src/corelib/global/qendian.h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, the solution to the problem was that there was a file earlier in the include path that was named `byteswap.h` and that was being included before the stdlib version of `byteswap.h`. Because that file did not contain the definitions of `bswap_64`, `bswap_32` or `bswap_16` the compiler errors were generated.

The fix was to rename the `byteswap.h` in the 3rd-party library to another name that did not conflict.